# Why VIBRATOR_SERVICE is not working consistently?

Tags: android, android-vibration

I have 2 phones:  one is on Android 4.1.1 and the other is on Android 4.1.2.

On Android 4.1.1 phone, the vibration intensity depends on the Haptic Feedback level while 4.1.2 phone vibration is strong and doesn't depend on this Haptic Feedback level at all.

I've been trying to find a way around it, but I just can't understand it.  I really don't want the Vibration Intensity depends on the Haptic Feedback because some users don't like turning on this Haptic Feedback.

Can someone please explain it?

Here is the code:

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've tried this code before, it wasn't any difference: same result.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct. Make sure that: 
under Setting, look for "Vibrate intensity" and make sure "notification" is not set to off.

This worked for me!